# How to check a character is belong or not belong to specific code page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, codepages

I want to print the character only if it is not belong to specific code page.

What function I can use for this purpose?

```
with open('in.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-16-le") as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        if not c.isprintable():
            continue
        if not ?????(c):
            print(c)
```

---

Version 2:

```
def is_supported(char, encoding):
    try:
        char.encode(encoding)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    return True
    
with open('in.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-16-le") as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        if not c.isprintable():
            continue
        if is_supported(c, 'cp950'):
            print(c + "(yes)")
        else:
            print(c + "(no)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the character in that code page. If if fails, it is not supported:

```
def is_supported(char, encoding):
    try:
        char.encode(encoding)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    return True

print(is_supported('ç', 'cp1252'))
print(is_supported('马', 'cp1252'))
```

```
True
False
```

Comment: I write version 2, but this function seems inaccurate, I use `繁简姬姫あa中` as input, output is :
繁(yes)
简(no)
姬(yes)
姫(no)
あ(yes)
a(yes)
中(yes)
, 
あ(yes) << this is wrong, this character is not in code page 950

Comment: @CLSo It *is* supported: `b'\xc6\xa6'.decode('cp950')` -> `'あ'`.  What is your reference?

Comment: If you go to Windows region setting, change "language for non-unicode programs" to cp950, and then paste `あ` to notepad, save as `ANSI` encoding, the character will be converted to `?`, that mean it is unable to store in cp950.

Comment: this setting, 

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mO04BE5AA5w/XhwLtbmSgcI/AAAAAAAAA0Q/fEI2lXZ13Y8o_eAKAYASYebetezjTPFdwCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/Change%2Bsystem%2Blocale.jpg

Comment: CP950 includes Hiragana, such as U+3041 to U+3093.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you: `''.join([chr(x) for x in range(0x3041,0x3094)]).encode('cp950')` works and converts `'ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをん'`.

Comment: OK, maybe my target is wrong. My actual target is, to write a program to test a character that unable convert to `ANSI` encoding in Windows Notepad under traditional chinese setting. Is it possible in Python?

Comment: I've repeated your results.  I can read and write a file with Python in CP950 and display it in the command prompt window, but Notepad is messing up.  My recommendation is to use UTF-8 which supports all codepoints and works with Notepad well (as long as you load a font that can display them).